# Pagesetup every sheet in Excel with vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript

I got a VBscript to convert all xls files in a folder (c:\folder) to pdf files. All columns are also set to fit one page, and with orientation landscape. The script works fine for Sheet1, but if the xls file has more then 1 sheets, it will only set the Pagesetup settings to the "active" sheet, and not to all.

How do I get my Pagesetup settings to apply to all sheets in all xls files in the folder?

```
Set xlObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.GetFolder("c:\folder")
For Each file In f.Files
set xlWB = xlObj.Workbooks.Open(file)
With xlWB.ActiveSheet.PageSetup
.Zoom = False
.FitToPagesWide = 1
.FitToPagesTall = False
End With    
thisFileName =Left(xlWB.FullName , InStrRev(xlWB.FullName , ".") - 1)
xlWB.Sheets.Select
xlWB.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat 0, thisFileName & ".pdf", 0, 1, 0,,,0
xlWB.close False
Next
xlObj.quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by removing `sht` in `next sht`

Following code worked:

```
    Set xlObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.GetFolder("c:\folder")
For Each file In f.Files
    set xlWB = xlObj.Workbooks.Open(file)
    for each sht in xlWB.Worksheets
        With sht.PageSetup 
            .Orientation = 2
            .Zoom = False
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = False
        End With 
thisFileName =Left(xlWB.FullName , InStrRev(xlWB.FullName , ".") - 1)
 xlWB.Sheets.Select
xlWB.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat 0, thisFileName & ".pdf", 0, 1, 0,,,0
next 
xlWB.close False
Next
xlObj.quit
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear how you want to handle exporting the other sheets?
As separate files, or all together in the same PDF?

```
Set xlObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.GetFolder("c:\folder")
For Each file In f.Files
    set xlWB = xlObj.Workbooks.Open(file)
    for each sht in xlWB.Worksheets
        With sht.PageSetup
            .Zoom = False
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = False
        End With 
        'can't use the same filename for all sheets !
        thisFileName = Left(xlWB.FullName , InStrRev(xlWB.FullName , ".") - 1)
        sht.ExportAsFixedFormat 0, thisFileName & ".pdf", 0, 1, 0,,,0
    next sht
    xlWB.close False
Next
xlObj.quit
```

Comment: Your code does not work for me. I get error on line 15. 
If a file contains more than one sheet, they should be exported to the same PDF. My original code handles all sheets to the same pdf as wanted, but only one of the sheets has the Pagesetup settings (FitToPage and so on).